# Не работает sql запрос в python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['buy'])
def category(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Выберите категорию!', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, choose)

def choose(message):
    purchase.name = message.text
    print(purchase.name)
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT price FROM adminTG_category WHERE name =?", (purchase.name,))
    purchase.price = cursor.fetchone()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите количество аккаунтов, сколько хотите купить')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, buy)

def buy(message):
    purchase.count = message.text

    try:
        merchant_key = "888"
        merchant_account = "888"
        merchant_domain_name = "888"
        currency = "UAH"
        count = purchase.count
        productName = purchase.name
        productPrice = purchase.price
        amount = count * productPrice
        ordernew = str(random.randrange(0, 99999))
        order_date = int(datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
        order = ordernew + "5"
        signature_data = f"***;{order};{order_date};{amount};{currency};{productName};{count};{productPrice}"
        signature = generate_signature(merchant_key, signature_data)
        params = {
            'transactionType': "CREATE_INVOICE",
            'merchantAccount': merchant_account,
            'merchantDomainName': merchant_domain_name,
            'merchantSignature': signature,
            'apiVersion': 1,
            'orderReference': order,
            'orderDate': order_date,
            'amount': amount,
            'currency': currency,
            'productName': [productName],
            'productPrice': [productPrice],
            'productCount': [count]

        }
```

при выполнении sql, ничего не происходит, выводит `purchase.name` и останавливается, проблема я так понимаю в sql запросе

Answer (score 0):

sql написан правильно. Возможно передаете name, которого нет в таблице adminTG_category. Попробуйте руками прописать name = 'vas9' вместо ?  и после

```
purchase.price = cursor.fetchone()
```

дописать

```
print(purchase.price)
```

и убедится что sql работает

Comment: Уже пробовал, когда вне функции и когда вручную прописывал